# How to check if a prop function in React is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to do an if statement. When the prop function is clicked(when you press OK button), I want to render ComponentA otherwise I want to render ComponentB.
Component B contains the button OK and I pass to it as a prop the function.
My if condition is not working properly. Any ideas?
My code:

```
clickButton() {
    console.log("yeah");
  }

render() {
    const {
    clickButton
    } = this.props;
    return this.clickButton ? (
      <ComponentA/>
    ) : (
    <ComponentB clickButton={clickButton}/>
    );
  }
}

Example.propTypes = {
  clickButton: PropTypes.func
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what isn't working properly and how it should work?

Comment: @rv7 it shows the ComponentA. Component B contains the Button OK and when the Button OK is clicked, then I want to show ComponentA. Otherwise I want to always show ComponentB.

Comment: It seems like what you want is for, when the button is pressed within `componentB`:  `1.`: The `clickButton` function to be called, `2.`: `ComponentB` to be hidden `3.`: `ComponentA` to be shown. Is that correct?

Comment: @OliverRadini exactly.

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for:

```
state = { clicked: false }

clickButton = () => {
    console.log("yeah");
    this.setState({clicked: !this.state.clicked})
}

render() {
    const { clicked } = this.state;
    return clicked ? (
      <ComponentA/>
    ) : (
    <ComponentB clickButton={this.clickButton}/>
    );
  }
}
```

If you want the state outside this component:

```
clickButton = e => {
    console.log("yeah");
    // so you will edit the value "clicked" passed as prop in the parent component
    this.props.clickButton(e)
}

render() {
    const { clicked } = this.props;
    return cicked ? (
      <ComponentA/>
    ) : (
    <ComponentB clickButton={this.clickButton}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a state value through the component, so the changed event can be caught, here's how

### Parent Component

```
state = {
    isButtonClicked: false
}

clickButton = () => {
    this.setState({ isButtonClicked: true })
}

render() {
    return (
        <Child isButtonClicked={this.state.isButtonClicked} clickButton={this.clickButton} />
    )
}
```

### Child Component

```
render() {
    const {
        isButtonClicked,
        clickButton
    } = this.props

    return this.isButtonClicked ? (
        <ComponentA/>
    ) : (
        <ComponentB clickButton={clickButton}/>
    )
}

Example.propTypes = {
    isButtonClicked: PropTypes.bool,
    clickButton: PropTypes.func
}
```

Comment: Good Answer. Your Child Component is my Parent and your Parent my Child. Thanks.